# Background doesn't change using media query on smaller devices

Tags: css, media

Here's the **style.css** where I've implement media queries:

```
body {
    background: url("http://voxie.co.uk/assets/img/infr/bgartL.png"), url("http://voxie.co.uk/assets/img/infr/bgart.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom left, bottom right;
    }

/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px)
    body {
    background: url("http://voxie.co.uk/assets/img/infr/bgartL.png"), url("http://voxie.co.uk/assets/img/infr/bgart.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom left, bottom right;
    }
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) 
    body {
        background: #b5ebf9 !important;
    }
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px)
    body {
        background: #b5ebf9 !important;
    } 
/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px)
    body {
        background: #b5ebf9 !important;
    }
```

And I've added this in the HTML, for it to detect (I think this is right):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

And obviously, linked to the above CSS file in the header.

But for some reason, the background image ALWAYS displays, instead of the colour `#b5ebf9`.

What am I doing wrong?! I've spent 1-2 days on and off trying to fix this! I tried...

- Making separate CSS sheets for each device , linking to those style sheets with the `media` tag included (no reaction whatsoever)
- Also tried removing the first body query from the above CSS - which just keeps the backgrounds in that color, across all devices, no background image at all! (I want the background image to show up on desktop screens.)

Please help!

Comment: You need to enclose the media queries in brackets:
@media(whatever) {
 body {
  //Some rules
 }
}

Answer (score 4):

You need those `{}` to regroup media queries:

```
body {
    background: url("http://voxie.co.uk/assets/img/infr/bgartL.png"), url("http://voxie.co.uk/assets/img/infr/bgart.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom left, bottom right;
}

/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    body {
        background: url("http://voxie.co.uk/assets/img/infr/bgartL.png"), url("http://voxie.co.uk/assets/img/infr/bgart.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:bottom left, bottom right;
    }
}
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    body {
        background: #b5ebf9 !important;
    }
}
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px){
    body {
        background: #b5ebf9 !important;
    } 
}
/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px){
    body {
        background: #b5ebf9 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: AHHHH WOW! I can't believe the solution was so simple!!! THANK YOU! It worked! (Obviously!) Bless you and your skills! :)

Comment: NP, Just a little tip. I know it is probably because you were testing, but always try to never use `!important`!

Comment: Really? That's interesting. Thanks, I may remove the 'important' bits. Thank you again for your eagle eyes :)

Comment: Ahah, if you are interrested, here a good reading on `!important` : http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this: 
@media only screen and (max-width: 979px) and (min-width:768px) {}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width:481px) {}

instead of just  @meadia

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 979px) and (min-width:768px) {
body {
        background: #b5ebf9 !important;
    }
}